# How to validate form on ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I am able to validate form by using `data-validation` attribute that is working properly without ajax form submission.

Now I am trying to validate my registration form using ajax submit I an trying following code but this is not working.

I am using [Jquery form validation](http://www.formvalidator.net/)

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", '#submitbtn', function (f) {
         f.preventDefault();
          var formData = $("#register").serialize();
       $.validate({
        form : '#registration-form',
         onError : function($form) {
          alert('Validation of form '+$form.attr('id')+' failed!');
        },
        onSuccess : function($form) {
          alert('The form '+$form.attr('id')+' is valid!');
          return false; // Will stop the submission of the form
 $.post('register', formData, function (data) {
             if (data.st === 1) {
                $('.msg').html(data.msg);
             }
            else {
              $('.msg').html(data.msg);
            }
          }).fail(function (response) {
                 $('.msg').html("Error");
            });
        }

      });

   });
 });
     });
```

How to achive this?